# Sort documents by whether a field is greater than 0?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Say I have a collection with documents like below:

```
{
  title: 'test2',
  count: 0
},
{  
  title: 'test1,
  count: 2
},
{
  title: 'test3',
  count: 3
}
```

I would like them to be displayed in the following order:

- First display all documents that have a count > 0 ordered by the title.
- After that display all documents that have a count == = ordered by the title.

Meaning the above data should display: `title1, title3, title2`

So basically sort by `{count > 0}: 1, title: 1`

I started with this:

`db.documents.find().sort({count: 1, title: 1})`

But this sorts by the count, rather than sorting by whether the count is greater than 0.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A trick would be using two helpers.

```
helperName: function() {
    return Somethings.find({count:{$gte:1}}, {sort: {title: //something})
}
helperNameTwo: function() {
    return Somethings.find({count:0}}, {sort: {title: //something})
}
```

Comment: Well I also want the docs that have a count of 0. Wouldn't this exclude them?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question clearly then. So you want to show all docs but the highest count should be on top/lowest on the bottom?

Comment: All documents should be included.  Documents with any count should be at the top ordered by title.  Documents with a count of zero should be below that ordered by title.  I give an example in my question that might help.

Comment: @AbeMiessler I understand. will you sort the titles alphabetically? I understand the 0 ones should be on the bottom

Comment: @AbeMiessler edited my question with a trick. you just need to sort the titles however you want if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the `find()` statement, but you could aggregate it as below:

- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) a field based on which the results will be sorted- `sort_field`, if the `count` value is `0`, give it a weight if `Infinity`, so that it comes up at the end.
- [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) based on the projected field.

*sample code:*

```
db.document.aggregate([
{$project:{"title":1,
           "count":1,
           "sort_field":{$cond:[{$eq:["$count",0]},Infinity,"$count"]}}},
{$sort:{"sort_field":1,"title":1}},
{$project:{"count":1,"title":1}}
])
```

*test data:*

```
db.document.insert([
{
  "title":"test2",
  "count": 0
},
{  
  "title":"test1",
  "count": 2
},
{
  "title":"test3",
  "count": 3
}
])
```

*test result:*

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567887f8b506fc2193a2269b"),
        "title" : "test1",
        "count" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567887f8b506fc2193a2269c"),
        "title" : "test3",
        "count" : 3
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("567887f8b506fc2193a2269a"),
        "title" : "test2",
        "count" : 0
}
```